# open ~/.heroku/cacert.pem: no such file or directory - why am I getting this error?

Tags: heroku

Only recently, I'm getting this error when I send commands via `heroku [command]` -- the command still executes correctly, but these errors appear one or more times.  I've never had to create this file before.

I am getting this error on both local dev environment and on cloud dev environment. I had to recreate these environments recently and have logged in via `heroku auth` and set up the appropriate `git remote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. If you update to a version newer than 3.37.1 it should be resolved.

Comment: do you mean a newer version of heroku-toolbelt? How can you do that, with homebrew? `brew upgrade heroku` just upgraded to 3.37.1 and not above it..

Comment: I did. Then I got: `Error: heroku-toolbelt 3.37.1 already installed`. I'm on OSX, btw.

Answer (score 4):

I found that my `~/.heroku/cacert.pem` file had no content and was 0 bytes, so I replaced it with the one from heroku's github page: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/data/cacert.pem
and now I don't get the `Error parsing ~/.heroku/cacert.pem` error any more.

Answer (score 1):

api.heroku.com is signed by

> /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance
>   CA-3

https://www.digicert.com/CACerts/DigiCertHighAssuranceCA-3.crt

So, put that key in the following location:

> ~/.heroku/cacert.pem

Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. It did nothing.